# How to deal with spatial autocorrelation at a global scale?

Tags: r, autocorrelation, spatial, ecology

I am working a dataset that shows the size of amphibians across the world. Both a Morans I test and a Mantel's test on the distance matrices between body size and location indicate that there is spatial auto-correlation with my data. The data is essentially ~7,500 points located around the world (image shown).

I have three several questions:

1. Is it possible that the mantel and moran's I test are showing significant p-values because of just the sheer sample size of the data?
2. My points are mostly concentrated and clustered on continents. Is this why I'm getting spatial auto-correlation? If so is this something to worry about?
3. If there is indeed spatial autocorrelation in the data, how should I account for it when I analyze the data? For example, if I wanted to ask the question of whether precipitation influences body size at a global scale, could I run a linear model of body size ~ temperature? I have played around with spatial mixed -effect models but the problem is that the sample size prevents the model from fully running (this happens on both my personal computer and a computing cluster that I have access to). I was thinking of analyzing the data separately based on continent.

If anyone has any input on this matter I'd really appreciate it! I am using R and RStudio to analyze this data.

[image: Image showing my points across the world]

Comment: 1) Are the points individual data or some summary data? 2) you include spatio-temporal tag. Why? Is there also a time-series aspect to the data , which is not explained in the post?

Comment: 1. summary data (averages of multiple frogs found at each location). 2.Must have been a typo that resulted in another tag.

Comment: Please add this additional info as an edit to the post, and not only as a comment. Not everybody reads comments! In addition, can you describe your data more completely, maybe showing a few rows of the data file? Specifically, is the size info a scalar variable only, or multivariate? Which other informtion do you have, which other variables? As a start you could make a better map (show us!), maybe by continent, colorcode the size (use transparent colors), that would give a visual view of the autocorrelation --- maybe add to the map eventual ecological barriers?

Comment: Re. your 3rd question: How about a partial mantel test - testing for an effect of the distances between temperature on the distances between body size, while partialing out the spatial distance. The downside is that it's a bit trickier to interpret the results when your response and predictors are distances rather than the original values.

Comment: I don't think the clustering of points on continents should be a problem. I take it you are calculating your geographic distance using a package like Geosphere, that takes into account that Earth is near spherical?